# Avalonia. Error MSB4018 : The "GenerateAvaloniaResourcesTask" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: .net, linux, avalonia

I'm getting this error when building avalonia app on Linux. No issues on windows. Any help is appreciated.

```
9>AvaloniaBuildTasks.targets(81,5): Error MSB4018 : The "GenerateAvaloniaResourcesTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '/home/user1/dev/src/app/**/*.axaml'.
File name: '/home/user1/dev/src/app/**/*.axaml'
   at System.IO.FileInfo.get_Length()
   at Avalonia.Build.Tasks.GenerateAvaloniaResourcesTask.Source..ctor(ITaskItem avaloniaResourceItem, String root) in /_/src/Avalonia.Build.Tasks/GenerateAvaloniaResourcesTask.cs:line 38
   at Avalonia.Build.Tasks.GenerateAvaloniaResourcesTask.<BuildResourceSources>b__18_0(ITaskItem r) in /_/src/Avalonia.Build.Tasks/GenerateAvaloniaResourcesTask.cs:line 73
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.ToList()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Avalonia.Build.Tasks.GenerateAvaloniaResourcesTask.BuildResourceSources() in /_/src/Avalonia.Build.Tasks/GenerateAvaloniaResourcesTask.cs:line 71
   at Avalonia.Build.Tasks.GenerateAvaloniaResourcesTask.Execute() in /_/src/Avalonia.Build.Tasks/GenerateAvaloniaResourcesTask.cs:line 133
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask)
9>------- Finished building project: app. Succeeded: False. Errors: 1. Warnings: 0
```

Funny thing it worked right after checking out from git, but subsequent rebuilds are failing. I've tried cleaning solution folders but no luck.

**EDIT**

Another tidbit for anyone coming across this. I've isolated the problem to JetBrains Rider, building my solution in Rider would result in the above error. I don't know how to fix it yet; so, I switched to vscode which I discovered works without errors.

Comment: '/home/user1/dev/src/app/**/*.axaml' is a pattern, not actual file name. Are you resolving actual file name before passing it down?

Comment: I believe this is one of the build steps in avalonia. For some reason it fails to locate axaml files

Comment: I have the same problem in JetBrains Rider, Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code on mac

Comment: The error can get bypassed by deleting the bin folder of your project, but this is not the ideal solution.